# Como contar o número cumulativo de ocorrências de um elemento em um vetor?

Tags: r

Suponha que tenho um vetor em R:

```
x <- c("a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c")
```

Preciso determinar, para cada posição `i` do vetor, quantas vezes o elemento `x[i]` apareceu até então. O resultado para o vetor acima seria

```
[1] 1 2 1 3 2 1
```

Como fazer esse cálculo de maneira eficiente e sem usar código nativo (C)? Por eficiente eu quero dizer algo que rode em um segundo ou menos em um vetor de 1 milhão de elementos (ex.: `x <- sample.int(1:99, size=999999, replace=T)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível usar a função `ave` da seguinte forma:

```
contagem <- ave(rep(1, length(x)), x, FUN=cumsum)
```

Primeiro, é gerado um vetor contendo apenas números 1, do tamanho do vetor de entrada (`rep(1, length(x))`). Dentro desse vetor são selecionados grupos de acordo com o valor de `x`, e dentro desses grupos é calculada a soma cumulativa (`cumsum`). Como o vetor só contém o número 1, a soma cumulativa resulta na sequência 1, 2, 3, ..., ou seja, uma contagem.

Comment: Rodrigo, nesta versão beta do stackoverflow em português, é prática comum fazermos perguntas e nós mesmos respondermos logo em seguida (para estimular a comunidade)?

Comment: @carloscinelli, a prática não tem sido muito comum, mas acho que é benéfica. É a comunidade que vai decidir quais perguntas são relevantes e quais respostas são mais adequadas. Eu mesmo já respondi minha própria pergunta e acabei aceitando a resposta de outra pessoa. Há uma discussão sobre essa prática no SO em inglês: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Comment: Eu também acho muito boa. Não é muito diferente de postar em um blog, mas para uma audiência maior. Também acho que ajuda a filtrar perguntas superficiais, que numa busca rápida já vão encontrar estas respostas aqui.