# Contegem de dados <- R

Tags: r

no R (rstudio)

Tenho um vetor `v1 <- c(543, 543, 543, 675, 675, 675, 675, 22, 22, 22, 90, 90, 87, 876, 867)`.

Gostaria de obter um vetor `vr` que representasse a contagem de `v1` (de forma crescente `1:n`) dos números que se repetem.

Em relação ao vetor anterior (`v1`) por exemplo: `vr <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2)`.

Desde já, muito obrigado!

Comment: Experimente a função `?table`. Mas a contagem não dá a da pergunta.

Comment: acabo de descobrir:

Comment: acabo de descobrir como realizar a tarefa:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/357/como-contar-o-n%C3%BAmero-cumulativo-de-ocorr%C3%AAncias-de-um-elemento-em-um-vetor/358#358

com:
"contagem <- ave(rep(1, length(x)), x, FUN=cumsum)"

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas para registro, é bem fácil de fazer isso com o pacote dplyr (sé que eum data frame, já que ele não trabalha com vetor).

```
library(dplyr)

v1 <- data.frame(num=c(543, 543, 543, 675, 675, 675, 675, 22, 22, 22, 90, 90, 87, 876, 867))
vr <- v1 %>%
  group_by(num) %>%
  summarise(repetido = n()) %>%
  arrange(repetido)
```